# Determine Win32_OptionalFeature's Parent feature

Tags: powershell, treeview, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

Back story, in 2012-R2, with Powershell v4.0 you have access to the `Get-WindowsFeature` cmdlet, which only works on Server OS.  It includes a Parent field which is needed to populate a treeview node, as child nodes are keyed to the parent node.

```
Get-WindowsFeature | select Name,DisplayName,Installed,Parent
```

From Windows 7/8.1, we cannot use the cmdlet, it doesn't run on Desktop OS.  We can see the same data here, but no parent ID field.  How can I determine the parent feature from WMI ?   Open to any answer that solves the problem.

```
GWMI Win32_OptionalFeature | select Name,Caption,InstallState
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In short, I am trying to generate a .csv dump from gwmi command that will be used to populate a treeview control based on currently installed features.  Kinda like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what your asking, but microsoft provide the [dism utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx)
to manage optional features.
Have a look at the `/get-features` and `/get-featureinfo` switch.

Here is an example on how to install RSAT (Remote Server Adminitration Tools)

```
start-process "powershell" -verb "runas"  -argumentlist "-noprofile -command 
    dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature 
    /FeatureName:RemoteServerAdministrationTools 
    /FeatureName:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles 
    /FeatureName:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD 
    /FeatureName:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell"
```